# class overrides and rewrites with namespace psr-4

Tags: php, oop, magento, overriding

i've worked with older php frameworks such as magento 1.x line where class rewriting (other then by core/community/local overrides) is done using framework config and framework getModel() or getSingleton() like calls, that have the opportunity to check the config before loading the class.

in other words, it could very well be that the config is loading a class under a completely different name not just path.

my question is, how could rewrites like this be supported in a newer psr4/composer aware framework where classes are instantiated directly with the `new` keyword instead of some getModel() call?

you could perhaps put the config checks directly into the autoloader instead of using a method to get the class, but then what about composer libs, using their own autoloaders like `vendor/autoload.php`? just chaining the autoloaders would give a hit on the wrong class if the rewrite uses another class name and both exists.

some link or explanation on how to perform both overriding (as in core/community/local) and rewrites (as in config myClassName -> newClassName) using newer namespace, psr4 & composer aware techniques would be most welcomed.